# Vertically printing in PHP

Tags: php, printing

Let's say  I have this array :

```
$names = array(

    'Abcd',
    'Efgh',
    'Jklm',
);
```

I would like to get it something like this :

```
$ php -f names.php

A  E  J
b  f  k
c  g  l
d  h  m
$
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive function for you. If you want the line-break to work in HTML, just change `\n` to `<br>`.

```
function verticalPrint($arr, $index = 0){
    $out = '';

    //Loop through the array $arr to get each string $str
    foreach($arr as $str){

        //Check if the $str is too short. If so, just save a space.
        //Otherwise, save the character at position $index and prepend a space to it
        if(strlen($str) <= $index)
            $out .= ' ';
        else
            $out .= ' '.substr($str, $index, 1);
    }

    //Remove all spaces in the beginning and the end of the string.
    $out = trim($out);

    //When all spaces in the beginning and the end are removed, is the string empty?
    //If so, we have done all the characters and $out is now finished.
    //If the string isn't empty, there might be more so we return our sting $out and
    //appends another call to this function to the end. Called recursion. This time 
    //with $index+1 so we take the next character.
    if(strlen($out))
        return $out."\n".verticalPrint($arr, $index+1);
    return $out;
}

$names = array(

    'Abcd',
    'Efgh',
    'Jklm',
);

print verticalPrint($names);

//Prints this
/*
A E J
b f k
c g l
d h m
*/
```

Read more about [Recursion >>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Oskar. I owe you one. Could you give me brief explanations on the code.I'm still begginer!

Comment: @ДимитърБиков No problem. I'll edit my answer with some explanations. Hold on.

Answer (score 4):

Use this code and assuming your array name is $name

```
for($i=0;$i<strlen($name[0]);$i++) {
for($j=0;$j<count($name);$j++) {
    echo $name[$j][$i];
}
echo '<br/>';}
```

Comment: @DevlshOne he doesn't need explode, you can access chars directly in string using `[]`

Comment: @DevlshOne, no need to use explode, only I have updated strlen in stead of count in first loop and it is working fine. I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that not only prints the way you want, but actually performs a transpose on the arrays themselves.......

```
$names = array('ABCD','EFGH','JKLM');
array_transpose($names);
$names = array('ABCDEF','GHIJKL','MNOPQR','STUVWX');
array_transpose($names);

function array_transpose($arr) {
    $a = count($arr);
    echo "<pre>\n";
    print_r($arr);
    $transarr = [];
    $verty = [];
    $chars = [];
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $i => $ar) {
        $chars = str_split($ar);
        foreach ($chars as $j => $char) {
            $transarr[$j][$i] = $char;
        }
    }
    foreach ($transarr as $j => $trans) {
        $transar = join($trans);
        array_push($verty,$transar);
    }
    print_r($verty);
    echo "</pre>\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABCD
    [1] => EFGH
    [2] => JKLM
)
Array
(
    [0] => AEJ
    [1] => BFK
    [2] => CGL
    [3] => DHM
)
 Array
(
    [0] => ABCDEF
    [1] => GHIJKL
    [2] => MNOPQR
    [3] => STUVWX
)
Array
(
    [0] => AGMS
    [1] => BHNT
    [2] => CIOU
    [3] => DJPV
    [4] => EKQW
    [5] => FLRX
)
```